# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am making a google sheet to track attendance for a team. I want the row with the name to highlight a specific color when a checkbox is on. I managed to write something that works for the specific row I'm working in, but any time I try to copy it over to other rows the range is just adjusted, so any time any checkbox from a column is on it highlights all the rows. Attached are pictures that show what I want it to do. I just need help figuring out how to copy this to other rows and keeping them all separated.

The code that is in each conditional formatting is this:

```
=$B2=True
=$C2=True
=or($D2,$E2)=True
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zwkuJOCBPIIoQ7cp0bV5IvidMVwdeIC0dShdjwKMSkE/edit?usp=sharing

I think the issue is with the code itself because when I copy it adds the new range, but the code stays the same.

[image: Sheet]

[image: Present]

[image: Absent]

[image: Late]

[image: Conditional Formatting 1]

[image: Conditional Formatting 2]

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your formulae are correct. change your range **A2:E2** to **A2:E** - that will solve it

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so much easier than I ever thought it would be.